# Git-flow during development phase

Tags: git, workflow

How do you handle git flow during sprint development?

I found that during development, some sprint tasks are interdependent, so it isn't possible to branch from master as it's too way back in the history and there is functionality required from the development branch to continue working on the sprint.

At the moment, I branch from development during the sprint and rebase the branch I'm working on from development. I found that using this way, master still always stable and we avoid doing lots of merges between branches to get the project to the state needed to continue development.

I think this part is missed everywhere, I couldn't find a documented way to avoid all this hassle.

And during development, hotfixes aren't branches from master, because the functionality we fix is probably an issue that was caused by feature conflicts, so we create hotfixes from development. Once development has all the sprint tasks merged and we fixed all hotfixes, we merge development into master. We don't use release branches as we don't have a pre-production server, so there's no point to having it.

But I feel like having development as a kind of master branch during development and change its meaning after development phases are quite confusing. Let me explain it better...

After development phases, the development branch will hold features based on the current master branch. While on development phase the new features will be based on the development branch.

Could you bring some light to me on how avoid this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say some things you apparently will think are wrong, so here is a source for reference: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

In normal gitflow, feature branches are created from development; so your point that you can't create feature branches from master and so you "fix this" by branching form development just means you're following gitflow.  I don't know where the idea to create feature branches from master would come from...

You mention rebasing from development... to where?  To master?  When?  In gitflow master only contains final release commits.  And regardless, rebasing anything that's been pushed (especially as part of routine workflow) isn't something I recommend.

If your hotfixes are branched form development, then you can't merge them into master until you're ready for everything up to that point in development to also be merged into master.  (You could cherry-pick them, but then you have an untested state of the code.)  If your fix has to wait for a regular release to go to master (and therefore to production), then it's not a hotfix.

If you were to change the practices I've mentioned so far to conform to gitflow, I think you'd start to see the value of release branches.  I suggest you forget what you know about gitflow and re-learn it.  Or, you can just abandon the idea that you're using gitflow at all and roll your own branching patterns, but if so you're ignoring the accumulated knowledge that led to gitflow as a solution to the problems you're experiencing.